# Two problems implementing jquery tabs and accordions from themeroller

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm new to jquery, and after doing quite a bit of reading and experimentation without solving this myself would like help with two problems on **sqlsolver_dot_com**:

1) The last tab visited always stays the a:visited color, even with a page refresh. Visiting another tab changes that but I'd like them all to appear unselected.

2) When I click on a tab with a name reference to one of the lower accordian panels it highlights it with a dashed line but I'd like it to actually slide open.
I'm placing x in the html in place of href, since I'm limited to one link per post.

JQUERY 

// Accordion
$("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3", active: false, collapsible: true, autoHeight: false });

// Accordion2
$("#accordion2").accordion({ header: "h3", active: false, collapsible: true, autoHeight: false });

// Tabs - the .addclass is to allow the external lind to the SP exam to load
$("#tabs1").tabs({
fx: [{opacity:'toggle', duration:'normal', duration:'fast', active: 'false'}]

.addClass('ui-tabs-vertical');
$("li.last a").unbind('click').each(function() {this.href = $.data(this, 'href.tabs');
});
   
HTML

```
<!-- code sample...
<body>
<div class="logo">
<div class="menu">
<div id="tabs1">
<ul>
       <li><a x="#articles">Articles</a></li>
<li><a x="#resources">Beginning Resources</a></li>
       <li><a x="#info">Wikis</a></li>
        <li class="last"><a x="x">SharePoint 70-576 exam blog</a></li>
       <li><a x="#about">About</a></li>
       </ul>
</div><!--ending tabs-->
</div><!--ending menu-->
<h1><a x="x">SQL Solver</a></h1>
<h2>SQL resources and training solutions<br /> suggested by <a x="x">Ramona   Maxwell</a></h2>
</div><!--ending logo-->

<div class="container"><!--starting page body-->

<div class="sidebar1">
<div id="accordion2">

<h3><a name="articles">Articles</a></h3>
<div><!-- One of these to contain each menu content item -->
<ul>
<li><a x="x">
SQL Saturday #55 Notes</a><br/><div class="byline">by Ramona Maxwell</div></li>
<li><a x="x">
Predictive Analysis<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;and Your Bottom Line</a>
<div class="byline">by Ramona Maxwell</div></li></ul>
<object id="MediaPlayer1" CLASSID="CLSID:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95"
```

and so on... -->

Answer (score 0):

Could 1) be a CSS style issue? set a CSS style for a and a:visited that is the same.

Comment: That's a good workaround that I'll use if I can't figure out why this happens. Really the visited pseudo-class isn't working at all, since if I click on more than one tab in a session only the last one before a refresh is darkened. If it were working as expected all tabs visited between page refreshes would darken.